# pass environmental variables into sudo?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, installation, sudo

when I was building LFS (Linux From Scratch), on the 2nd pass for GCC, in attempt to do sudo make install, I got the error stating `/bin/bash: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found` which will work normally without sudo, but I can't install it without sudo as permission is denied, and I don't want to mess around with permissions in my /tools directory.

How do I get sudo to recognize this command?

Comment: This may not work depending on your sudo configuration, but try `sudo PATH=$PATH <yourcommand>`.